# Different Editions of SQL Version in Same machine

Tags: sql-server

Can you please let me know if we can install two different editions of SQL Server 2014 in Same machine

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50763/multiple-versions-of-sql-server-on-the-same-development-machine

Answer (score 1):

> Generally yes. Your services on some version will continue running normally unless you manually make some changes.
>
> [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143694.aspx) is a good article on MSDN on site-by-side support for different
>   versions of SQL Server.
>
> [This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43854/can-i-install-sql-server-2012-on-a-machine-with-2008-r2-already) thread is a good read too.